# In the set {${{n-k+1,n-k+2,...,n }}$} contains at most how many positive integer divisors of $\binom {n}{k}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider a positive integer $k$ , when $n$ is a positive integer that changes not less than $k$. In the set {${{n-k+1,n-k+2,...,n }}$} contains at most how many positive integer divisors of $\binom {n}{k}$

Let $n=k!$ , we have $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{(n-k+1)(n-k+2)...n}{k!}$

$\Rightarrow \binom{n}{k} = (n-k+1)(n-k+2)...(n-1)$

Let $S:= $ {${n-k+1,n-k+2,...,n }$}

So I think the set $S$ contains at most $k-1$ divisors of $\binom{n}{k}$ . I will prove that there exists an element of $S$ that is not a divisor of $\binom{n}{k}$ .But I don't have any idea yet, I hope to get help from everyone. Thanks very much!

Comment: You already proved that $S$ contains $k-1$ divisors by showing that $\binom{n}{k}=(n-k+1)(n-k+2)..(n-1)$ right??